# I deleted 'data' in recovery mode on my mac, now the majority of the disk isn’t detected by disk utility and MacOS can't be reinstalled

Tags: macos, mac, disk-utility, install, apple-silicon

I wanted to clean install MacOS on my mac, but I didn't have the password for my old icloud account so I went into recovery mode and into Disk Utility and I erased 'data' this completely deleted it, after this only 5GB of my 512GB SSD is partitioned or even able to be partitioned Disk Utility just won't let you, I also tried reinstalling MacOS through recovery mode, but I get to the stage of choosing the disk to install on and am stuck here as Nothing Shows up, I even tried using a USB to install it on to but it just threw errors.
The 'pie' in disk utility: [image]
Please help me as this is my main machine and I really need it.
(It's Been 5 days and we still haven't sovled the problem)
I use the MacBook Air 2020 M1 model if it helps at all
After running “Diskutil list” in Recovery mode terminal, It notices the free space of 494.3GB but it seems to be unformatted? how can I format it so my mac will recognise it in disk utility and MacOS Installer?:[image]
Images of Disk utility in recovery mode:[image: Something Else?][image: Internal SSD]

Comment: Clean installs are largely unnecessary. Next time, use "Erase all content" in Settings (Preferences) under the Apple menu. Your best course is to take it to an Apple Store. Otherwise, can you show us some photos of Disk Utility in Recovery mode?

Comment: Erase all content didn’t work as I needed to log out of an iCloud account that didn’t exist anymore, I will gladly add images though

Comment: @benwiggy I'd also really rather not have to go to the apple store as my nearest apple store is in Charlestown (50 Minute Drive) the next closest being Sydney (1h 30m drive)

Comment: There is no guarantee that you'll get answers faster here, especially because these things usually require a lot of back and forth.

Comment: Anyway, after booting to Recovery, can you open Terminal, run `diskutil list` and add a picture of that as well?

Comment: @nohillside thanks for the insight I have added the requested image

Answer (score 1):

By way of comparison, here's my readout (for a 1Tb drive):

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         994.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +994.7 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            8.9 GB     disk3s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 8.9 GB     disk3s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 4.8 GB     disk3s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                762.1 MB   disk3s3
   5:                APFS Volume Data                    432.0 GB   disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      5.4 GB     disk3s6
```

You seem to have destroyed the `Apple_APFS` Container, which contains the OS, Data, and other volumes.

Check the Partition of the DEVICE, and see if you can add a partition for the remaining space. Then see if you can install the OS again.

If that really isn't working, then you'll need to take it to an Apple Store, as it's royally messed up.

Whatever you did, that's not how you do a clean install. You shouldn't need to mess with the disk format at all. Use the option in System Preferences ("Settings" in Ventura) to Erase all Content.

Comment: Please tell me, how do I check the partition of the device?

Comment: @SlothGamer Select the device, and then click the partition icon.

Comment: Yeah that ain’t working I click partition and it shows it’s filled (only 5GB)

Comment: @SlothGamer Can you not adjust the "pie" at all?

Comment: no not at all, It's only showing 5GB is the full thing, it's not adjustable I'll attach a picture.